# How to delete documents where two fields have different values

Tags: php, mongodb

I am using MongoDB PHP Library to manipulate mongodb data.

docs: https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/master/tutorial/crud/

I want to delete  records that two fields have different values,for example:

there is a collection:

```
    $collection = [
        ['_id' => 'xxx', 'name_from_card' => 'foo', 'name_from_passport' => 'fooo'],
        ['_id' => 'xxx', 'name_from_card' => 'bar', 'name_from_passport' => 'bar'],
        ['_id' => 'xxx', 'name_from_card' => 'baz', 'name_from_passport' => 'bazz'],
        ['_id' => 'xxx', 'name_from_card' => 'qux', 'name_from_passport' => 'qux']
    ];
```

If the values of `name_from_card`  and `name_from_passport` are different in a record,I will delete this record.In above example, record `1` and `3` will be deleted.

How to do it with MongoDB PHP Library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`$where`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/). You need the JavaScript expression to compare the fields, and in most language implementations this is simply expressed as a string:

```
$collection->deleteMany([ '$where' => 'this.name_from_card !== this.name_from_passport' ])
```

The [`deleteMany()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/master/reference/method/MongoDBCollection-deleteMany/) method applies to "all" matched documents, rather than just the first match.